# How to remove trailing in url (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to make a movie website with react and there's a search movie page that when the user search a movie, a bunch of movies based on the user search query will appear and when that movie is clicked it will redirect to the movie detail page

Here's the search movie page:

[image]

The problem here is when I click the movie it redirects to `"/search/movie/(id)"` instead of just `"/movie/(id)"`. Because of that it will lead me to a blank page because there's no component assigned in `"/search/movie/(id)"`.

[image]

Here's the code for the movie item:

```
function MovieCard(props){
  return(
    <NavLink to={`movie/${props.id}`} end>
      <div className="movie-card">
        <img src={props.imgLink} width='250px' height='300px' alt={props.title}/>
        <p>{props.title}</p>
        <p>{props.releaseDate}</p>
        <p>{props.rating}<img src="star-icon2.png" width='18px' height='18px'/></p>
        <button className="add-to-my-list-button">Add to my list</button>
      </div>
    </NavLink>
  )
}
```

And here's the routing code:

```
function Main() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar webName={'MovieStash'}/>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route path="/watchedmovies" element={<WatchedMovie/>}/>
        <Route path="/search" element={<Search/>}/>  
        <Route path="/movie/:id" element={<MovieData/>}/>                                        
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

I tried to modify the routing code to assign the movie detail page to the `"/search/movie(id)"` path with this code:

```
function Main() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar webName={'MovieStash'}/>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route path="/watchedmovies" element={<WatchedMovie/>}/>
        <Route path="/search" element={<Search/>}/>  
        <Route path="/search/movie/:id" element={<MovieData/>}/> (the line of code i add as my temporary solution)
        <Route path="/movie/:id" element={<MovieData/>}/>                                        
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

Do you guys have any solution on how to make the searched movies redirects to `"/movie/(id)"` instead of `"/search/movie/(id)"` so that I can remove the line of code I add as my temporary solution?